# Where are Android styles defined?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-theme, android-styles

Is there anywhere that I can view the visual differences between the various Android Styles, at least for AOSP version of Android?

Specifically, if I want to view all the difference is TextAppearance styles, is there anywhere that would show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more convenient way if you didn't download the AOSP.

These resources are shipped with Android SDK release, under the directory `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platforms/android-21/data/res` you can see the definition and implementation by `Ctrl + Mouse left click` in your app development environment (Eclipse or Android studio).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the actual code for Android styles.xml this here it is: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Try to also look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyingStyles) in order to understand the usage of styles and themes in your app.